Make label shape marker in ArcGIS Pro center at the top of polygon
I am trying to make a label shape marker centered on the top of a polygon.
This can be done easily in the actual symbology in ArcGIS Pro. In the layer pane of Pro you just tell the marker where to anchor and that's it.
The label shape marker has been difficult to make the same changes. I have made a symbol in the Text fill symbol window and made a shape marker in there. In the Format Embedded Polygon Symbol window, I changed the Position area of the layer to anchor at the top of the polygon but it is only changing a within the the middle range of the polygon. If I choose to change the layer labelling placement to Boundary placement, and make all settings to be centered, it just picks a place on the far right of the polygon. Nothing that I changed in the settings to make the shape marker go to the center of the top of the polygon, has worked.
What is currently happening.

The paws are what I want to happen.


Are you asking to place a label where you show the paw icon?

Yes! That is exactly right.

I don't believe what you are asking for is possible through labelling. Typically if one wants bespoke placement of labels you would create a standard label and then convert them to annotations. Then you have to manually move and customise each label. I've always understood annotations are are for precision placement of labels when automated approaches don't work.
But what if you have thousands of polygons to label, you either have to take the hit of bespoke placement of annotations or come up with some other automated approach.  One such idea that leaps to mind, is create an envelope around each feature (minimum bounding box), then take the midpoint of north side of envelope and create a perpendicular line that tracks south. Take the intersection of that line with the polygon and that's your "paw" point then pass through the text you want as a label. Symbolise the point as nothing but turn on its labelling.

Thanks for answering. I don't think it is possible either to reliably place the label in the same place every time as a symbol marker in the label part of the polygon shape. I have thousands of polygons to do, so annotation would not work.
